# Unexpected inconsistency, root filesystem requires manual fsck, boots to (initramfs)

Tags: 17.04, fsck, initramfs, busybox, dell-vostro

This shows up on my screen when I boot my laptop on Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: Please try to include some textual error message into the question instead of an image. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do what is say ... run `fsck /dev/sda7` and reboot.
If you add a `-y` (`fsck -y /dev/sda7`) fsck will automatically answer 'yes' to all questions.